# Can I use 14/3 wire to connect a new switch on a branch in a 4-way circuit?

Tags: wiring

I have a 4 way switching dilemma. A new box and 14/3 wire was added to one of the boxes in the middle of the run. Can I make all of the switches work without rewiring the whole thing? 
If need be I can change the 14/2 wire from the light to run to box 3 instead of box 1 - Other changes are major! THANKs - here's the drawing showing the current wiring runs (only) - Tell me what switches I need and how to connect them please[image]..

Comment: All 4 boxes have switches?

Answer (score 4):

### You'll need something a bit fancier than a standard switch to bail you out of this mess

With standard four-way switches, a mid-loop spur like the one between boxes 2 and 3 would require a /4 cable instead of the /3 you've run.  However, a more sophisticated system like the Lutron Maestro can handle this without a hitch: simply replace the switch in box 1 with a MA-S8AM and the rest of the switches with MA-AS'es.  These can work with only a line, a load, and a single interconnect wire connecting the accessory switches together, which allows for the mid-loop spur you have to be run with the cable already in the wall.

Comment: I have used these switches many times best way for 3/4 way dimmers without major rewiring.+

Answer (score 0):

the solution 3-phase is referring to will indeed work, however is can be expensive.  How 3-way's and 4-way's are designed to work is that you plan for two three ways, one on each end of the switching group.  Between the two three ways two travelers are run and one common; usually a 14-3 cable.  Then you can install any number of 4-ways between these two three ways.  All the 4-ways do is reassign the two travelers to the other wire. The way you have it drawn will not work.  Run two 14-2 cables between box two and box three.  No need to carry the common out to box three. Go on-line to see some simple drawings of 3-way and 4-way switching configurations.  Happy switching.

Comment: OP stated that wiring changes would be difficult.   However, if it's possible to replace the cable from box 2=>3, a single 14/4 would be a cleaner install than two 14/2s.

Comment: the 14-4 would work and meet code as long as all four wires are insulated.